# Am I going to run into issues using Lets Encrypt SSL on WPMU? (Nginx)

Tags: wordpress, ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt, wpmu

I can't begin building my WPMU server until this evening so I thought I would ask the question here to see if anyone has experience with this scenario.

Setting up a WordPress Multisite with Lets Encrypt SSL.
Using Sub-directories.

I just want to ensure there is no issue with Common Name or something similar.

Comment: It is clear you have not done sufficient research before posting this question.  A simple search on "SSL Common Name" would have addressed your concerns regarding your proposed configuration.  Going forward please ask questions about specific problems you are having.  General questions about things that may or may not be problems are not usually constructive.

Answer (score 0):

SSL Certificates have nothing to do with sub-directories, thus it will not matter.  The Common Name in SSL identifies the host (Eg. www.example.com).

If you are using sub-domains it would still be easy to accomplish.

The example below will generate a single certificate for example.com, www.example.com, en.example.com and fr.example.com.

```
certbot-auto certonly --rsa-key-size 4096 --standalone -d example.com \
-d www.example.com -d en.example.com -d fr.example.com
```

In your nginx site configuration, you will specify the single certificate which will be valid for all the domains yous specified with certbot.

```
server {
    ...
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ...
}
```